# How to grab specific cell values in Excel sheet using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working on the code below. How can I grab a specific cell value like highlighted boxes:

[image]

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
file_xlsx = "Book1.xlsx"
yellow_cell = pd.read_excel(file_xlsx , sheet_name='Temp', usecols= 'Season')
red_cell = pd.read_excel(file_xlsx , sheet_name='Temp', usecols= 'Ave')
```

So at the end, I want to print

```
print(yellow_cell)
print(red_cell)
```

the result to be

```
Summer
12,10,8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_excel("/path/to/file/Book1.xlsx", sheet_name="Temp")

yellow_cell = df.query("Group.eq('B')")["Season"].squeeze()
red_cell = df.query("Group.eq('D')")["Ave"].squeeze()
```